# Java - How to click on canvas in selenium?

Tags: selenium, click

I have a canvas element (Width: 720, Height : 174). This canvas has 16 parts. I tried

```
Actions.moveToElement(we,(720/16)*3,1).click().perform();
```

I want it to click in part 3 of the canvas,
but it always clicks in the first part. Please help!

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
Actions.moveToElement(we,0,0).moveByOffset((720/16)*3,1).click().build().perform();
```

Comment: What browser are you using? What version browser and webdriver?
You should be confident that native actions are supported and available

Comment: i use FF 25, selenium 2.33.0. It clicks on canvas but always is in first part.

Answer (score 1):

For getting co-ordinates of the elements inside canvas tag use any online ruler

```
Actions clickAt = new Actions(d);
clickAt.moveToElement(d.findElement(By.xpath("your canvas id here")), 60, 30).click();
clickAt.moveToElement(d.findElement(By.xpath("your canvas id here")), 90, 30).click();
clickAt.build().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Include the Sikuli library in your project.
2. Take a screenshot of that area where you want to click and save it in your system with name, perhaps `"openButton"` for the following example: (Better if small in area size)
3. Use the Pattern and Screen classes:

   ```
   Screen obj = new Screen();

   Pattern openButton = new Pattern(filepath + "OpenButton.PNG");

   s.click(openButton);
   ```

See "[How to use Sikuli with Selenium](https://www.guru99.com/sikuli-tutorial.html)" for more information.